# How can I read/write an image in C++ using just boost/standard library?

Tags: c++, image, boost, io

Is this possible? It doesn't matter what format the image is, but I have to be able to open it, read pixel data into some sort of array, create a new image using a modified set of pixel data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Boost.GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) has a good [video tutorial](http://stlab.adobe.com/gil/presentation/index.htm) which shows you how to read/write and process raw image data in a very generic, yet efficient, way.

Answer (score 0):

You need code to encode and decode the formats you want to support. You can do this yourself (not really ideal/practical,) you can embed encoding/decoding libraries (like libpng, for example,) or you can embed image libraries like DevIL.

Boost seems to include some sort of image access library known as [Boost.GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html). I really don't know much about it, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the [TARGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) image format for your needs. You just read/write a few values in a header, then the rest is an uncompressed array of RGBA pixel data. You won't even need Boost!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/). This library is extremely easy to use. You only have to include a header file in your code and set some parameters when compiling and that's it! I've used CImg with MingW and GCC.